# Why are the preferences in my Android PreferenceFragment indented?

Tags: android, preferencefragment

When I create my PreferenceFragment, all of the preferences in the preference category are indented.

When I do this in a new project with default settings (just an Activity and PreferenceFragment), the preferences appear just fine (no indentation).

[image]

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings);
    }

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Game Setup">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="checkbox_randomize_opponents"
            android:title="Randomize Opponents"
            android:summary="Randomize opponents after round 1" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "smaller app"?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your UI using the Hierarchy Viewer?
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer

Comment: I mean an app with just an activity, a fragment and a preference fragment.  Gonna try that now Daniel, first time using Hierarchy Viewer, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Found out it is in my theme, still don't understand it though. When I comment this out, it works.  <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: Furthermore, when I set my own icon via android:icon in my style, it will place it in front of my preference which explains why setting transparent would "indent" my preferences.  I guess I am just confused as to why it would do this, as I want to set my own icon that doesn't preface my preferences.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to put the relevant portion of your theme file please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, preferences have no icons. Icons are drawables, and when you specify one using the `android:icon` attribute, the preference fragment will display what ever drawable you have set.

`android:color/transparent` is a *drawable*. Setting this as the `android:icon`, in addition with the fact that preference fragment has a fixed size for icons, will tell the fragment to show the icon. In this case, it's a transparent square of fixed dimensions.

Try changing it to `@android:color/black` and instead of the "indent", you should see a black square with fixed dimensions.

If you want no icon, you can either set the icon attribute to `android:icon="@null"` or just remove the attribute entirely (default is no icon).

Comment: Thanks ataulm.  The reason I had the icon set to transparent was because my entire app was using the theme and I wanted to remove the icon from the action bar.  Instead, I found the appropriate way to remove the icon from the actionbar without using my main apptheme. Thanks again!

Comment: no worries. For others visiting this, the appropriate way is to have a theme for the specific activity you want to override the styles for.